# Improving python code - Object Oriented (writing a deposit and charging code for bank)

Tags: python, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I wrote 2 codes for a task that asked for a code to be used for the deposit and charging functions, and I want to see if there is a way to improve my code; make it more generic, or use `__init__` function for if for example.

```
class Account:
    last_id = 1000

    def __init__(self, customer):
        self.customer = customer
        Account.last_id += 1
        self.id = Account.last_id
        self._balance = 0

#deposit

    def deposit(self, amount):
        if amount > 0:
            self._balance += amount
            print('Deposit: ' + str(self._balance))
        else:
            print('Operation was successful')
        pass


#charge

    def charge(self, amount):
        if amount > self._balance:
            raise NotEnoughBalanceException(
                "Not enough balance in your account " + str(self._balance))

        if amount <= 0:
            raise NegativeAmountException("Operation can't be done. Choose another amount")
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Your `charge` method only handles error conditions without changing the account balance. You don't need `pass` in either case where it's used.